# Is there a way for a plugin to add an attribute to the <html> tag of a theme?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm currently working on an appcache plugin for WordPress. One thing that it should do is add a manifest reference in the `<html>` tag of the site. It has to resemble something like this:

`<html manifest="manifest.appcache">`

Is there any way of doing this programmatically within a plugin? My current idea would be to identify the `<html` part of a theme's header file and inject the manifest using something like `str_replace()`. However, I can't see a way of filtering the output of the `get_header()` function either via the `get_header()` action or `load_template()` function.

If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Welcome to WP.SE! As a starter: No, there is no filter. You will have to introduce theme authors to your API. But the really hard thing will be to save your manifest file somewhere. Not everything is `0777` in WP for a reason ;)

Comment: Thanks @kaiser, I had anticipated the permissions issue. In that instance I'd have the plugin provide instructions for adding the manifest yourself (in the same way that core tells you about editing your .htaccess file). For the output filtering, sigh. Never mind! Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: I'm curious if you ever got your plugin working? Because I tried to test AppCache earlier and either I was doing everything wrong, or PHP doesn't seem to be compatible with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327024/whats-wrong-with-my-appcache-manifest-test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably use the [`language_attributes` filter](http://queryposts.com/function/language_attributes/) (from the `language_attributes()` function) to add it.

It should receive an output like `lang="en"` and you can add to it before printing to the `<html>` tag:

```
add_filter( 'language_attributes', function( $attr )
{
    return "{$attr} manifest=\"manifest.appcache\"";
} );
```

or without a anonymous function

```
add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'wpse140730_add_manifest_to_language_attributes' );

function wpse140730_add_manifest_to_language_attributes($output) {

    return $output . ' manifest="manifest.appcache"';

}
```

Comment: Genius! I totally didn't think about using the `language_attributes` filter. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to help out!